# Can't get an import to complete on magento 2

Tags: magento2

As you can see, my import is checked for bad data and it goes on to the final step with no errors in the exception log or any errors on the screen but after it finishes, it never adds any products. Where do I go from here?

[image]

UPDATE:

Here is the download link for my csv file:

http://www.filedropper.com/wayneimport

UPDATE 2:

When I try to upload the file, it gets stuck on the please wait loading image
[image]

UPDATE 3:

Here is what the console says
[image]

Comment: after that have you `reindex`?

Comment: What are you trying to import Product/Customers? Can you please paste error CSV column, what it's showing error

Comment: Share your CSV file to investigate

Comment: @chirag Yes I performed reindex after but the issue doesn't seem to be related to reindex

Comment: @AnkitShah I'm trying to import products only and I updated to include a link to my uploaded csv file

Comment: @FranckGarnier I updated to include a link to my csv file

Comment: In the please wait loading state. right click and inspect element look for console if there's any error and post it here. Thanks

Comment: @MazeStricks No errors in the console at all. I updated my post to show a screenshot

Comment: Ok I'll download your csv and look for errors that might cause the problem.

Comment: How about the images of this csv where did you place it?

Comment: I Think I know the problem. I checked your csv file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50119/discussion-between-mazestricks-and-user3610374).

Comment: from your screenshot I think You have enable the cloudflare rocketloader, login your cloudflare account goto speed and turn off your cloudflare rocketloader and clear magento cache and check again

Comment: @chirag You were correct. The rocketloader was causing the issue and when I disabled it, the import worked perfectly. Please create an answer and I will mark it as solved

Comment: Hi @user3610374 Your issue is solved?

Comment: @AnkitShah Yes it is

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your screenshot,
I think You have enabled the **`CloudFlare rocket loader`**.

Do this Steps:

1) log in your **CloudFlare** account.

2) go to speed and turn off your **`CloudFlare rocket loader`**

3) clear Magento **cache** and check again.

Or you can also bypass specific URL,

See this [How do I exclude a specific URL from CloudFlare's caching?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172316-How-do-I-exclude-a-specific-URL-from-CloudFlare-s-caching-)